# Best way to execute commands to TCP/IP console from PHP

Tags: php, console, tcp, fsockopen

Before I start, excuse my english, I'm from Holland :)

I have a question regarding the use of PHP's [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

**My Prerequisites**

So basically, I have a Windows program running in the background which has a remote console over TCP/IP that I need to connect to so I can execute a few commands. I am able to connect to that console with [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Download), and execute my commands without any problems.

**My Solution**

So the issue I have right now, is that I need to be able to execute these commands from the browser. I have searched the interwebs for best ways to do this and what I found was to use PHP's [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to connect to my console. The code I tried is as follows:

```
$SOCKET = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 12101, $errno, $errstr);

if($SOCKET){
 echo "Connected!";
}

$firstRead = fread($SOCKET, 8000);

echo($firstRead);
```

And using [fputs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) to send a command:

```
fputs($SOCKET, "HELP \r\n");
```

And after, reading out my response with this:

```
$response = fread($SOCKET, 8000);
echo $response;
```

**The Problem(s)**

But I have encountered a few weird problems when testing this.
As soon as I execute a command like "HELP", I can see from my KiTTY session that the command was executed and that I got a response, but when I read out the response with "fread" I get nothing. But when I use a loop to read it out like this, it reads something from the console at the second try almost everytime:

```
do {
    $response = fread($SOCKET, 8000);
    $i++;
} while (strlen($response) < 5 || $i < 5);
```

( Sometimes, it DOES read something from console on first try, but mostly it only reads something on second try ).

**The Question**

Now my question(s) is(are), why does it behave so strangely? And is it because I am doing something wrong? And is this really the best way to do this?

**sidenote**

When this works, I need to be able to call these PHP functions ( or something similar ) with a bunch of [AJAX requests](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and get the response to show in the browser. This is an absolute MUST so please keep this in mind when writing a possible answer :)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a socket with `fsockopen` in PHP you might also want to specify if it is blocking or non-blocking, in case of a non-blocking socket the function `socket_read` will return `false` on error or if the connection was closed, or empty string until some data is received, in case of a blocking socket instead when you read on it, it will block until there is some data to read (or empty string if a timeout is hit).
The behavior you described seems to be non-blocking.

For changing the blocking type there are: `socket_set_block` and `socket_set_nonblock`.

When your code with sockets works, there won't be any problems with AJAX requests, but keep in mind to set a timeout in PHP socket, otherwise if the server is down or simply too slow the request will fail with error (a timeout from php if set_time_limit is exceeded, which is a fatal error, or a JavaScript one with the browser timeout constant).

Here are the links to manual of [socket_read](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php) and [socket_write](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php), which I think are more appropriated of `fread` and `fputs`.